# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selector' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-migrate

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­I am developing a website for my friend in wordpress, using woocommerce and when I wanted to integrate stripe, I noticed that the checkout page is giving javascript error, it says­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selector' of undefined
```

This is the part of code, it is actually jQuery Migrate:­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

```
    /*! jQuery Migrate v1.4.1 | 
       (c) jQuery Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
 "undefined" == typeof jQuery.migrateMute && (jQuery.migrateMute = !0), 
       /* The line above is the part that is giving error */
    function(a, b, c) {
      function d(c) {
        var d = b.console;
        f[c] || (f[c] = !0,
        a.migrateWarnings.push(c),
        d && d.warn && !a.migrateMute && (d.warn("JQMIGRATE: " + c),
        a.migrateTrace && d.trace && d.trace()))
  }
```

Plus, I noticed that in checkout page, when I wanted to change means of payment, for example from bank transfer to paypal, the definition tooltip is not changing it's position. For example, initially it is showing what's Bank transfer, but you check radio button of paypal, the definition is not changing to paypal's definition.

[image: this is the screenshot from the checkout page]

If you want to see the website itself, it's here: thebeardconnection.se, try to add a product to cart and go to checkout page, you'll see the problem.

Please, help me if you can, it is really important. Thank you)

Comment: http://thebeardconnection.com not working

Comment: you meant http://thebeardconnection.se I figured out ;)

Comment: yes, actually it was .se I'm terribly sorry #autocorrectproblems lol

Comment: Try using jQuery in no-conflict mode and if you are using jQuery as `$`, replace it with `jQuery`

Comment: I don't see any `$` there that could be replaced with jQuery (((